# Why are there no quotation marks around the years attribute when using dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was stuck on this mistake for such a long time but then realized that when using dataframe to filter out years, there's no quotation mark. Isn't the year variable classed as a string in a csv? or is it just numerical since there's no letters in it? Is this also the same for float numbers too? Such that to filter out float numbers you don't have do the quotation marks around it?

ie the correct method is:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("somerandom_with_years_as_an_attribute.csv")
specific_year = df[df['years'] == 2020]
```

not:

```py
specific_year = df[df['years'] == '2020']
```

Comment: Clearly it's *not* a string, otherwise you'd need quotes.  I suspect pandas is parsing the input data with `read_csv` and casting everything it can to numerical types

Comment: Always good practice to the check the datatypes with df.dtypes after reading a csv-file into a dataframe. May save you a lot of time as it is not evident how the datatypes change from csv to dataframe.

Comment: Or use `read_csv` in conjunction with `dtype: 'str'`, so that all columns are explicitly casted as a string